# Durandal - jQuery $.getJSON promise not working as expected

Tags: jquery, single-page-application, durandal, promise

I'm trying to follow the example given to create a module in the Durandal docs, located here: http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Creating-A-Module/

I'm unable to figure out why my promise object isn't updating my observable array. Here's what I have so far:

**main.js**

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'text': 'durandal/amd/text'
    },
    urlArgs: "bust=" +  (new Date()).getTime() //this is a cache buster for js, remove before deployment
});

define(['durandal/app', 'durandal/viewLocator', 'durandal/system', 'durandal/plugins/router', 'lib/utils', 'lib/config', 'lib/backend'],
    function(app, viewLocator, system, router, utils, config, backend) {
        system.debug(true);

        var Backend    = backend;
        window.service = new Backend(config.service_url);

        app.title = 'Huddle';
        app.start().then(function() {
            viewLocator.useConvention();

            router.useConvention();
            router.mapRoute('projects', 'viewmodels/projects/list', 'Projects', true);

            app.adaptToDevice();
            app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell', 'entrance');
        });
    });
```

**viewmodels/projects/list.js**

```
define(function (){
    return {
        projects: ko.observableArray([]),

        activate: function () {
            var self = this;

            return service.getProjects().then( function ( jqxhr ){
               self.projects(jqxhr);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**views/projects/list.html**

```
<section class="projects-list" data-bind="widget: { kind: 'sortable_table', items: projects }">
```

**lib/backend.js**

```
define(function(require){
  var backend = function (service_url) {
    this.url = service_url;
  };

  backend.prototype.getProjects = function(){
    var jqxhr = $.getJSON(this.url+'/projects');

    return jqxhr;
  };

  return backend;
});
```

**Service Call response**

```
{
    "projects": [
        {
            "id": <project id>,
            "title": "Project One",
            "description":"This is a description",
            "created_by": <user_id>,
            "created_date": "12341234",
            "modified_by": <user_id>,
            "modified_date": "12341234",
            "favorite": true,
            "users": [
                <user id>,
                <user id>,
                <user id>
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": <project id>,
            "title": "Project Two",
            "description":"This is a description",
            "created_by": <user_id>,
            "created_date": "12341234",
            "modified_by": <user_id>,
            "modified_date": "12341234",
            "modified_by": 394839248239,
            "favorite": true,
            "users": [
                <user id>,
                <user id>,
                <user id>
            ],
            "favorite": true
        },
{
            "id": <project id>,
            "title": "Project Three",
            "description":"This is a description",
            "created_by": <user_id>,
            "created_date": "12341234",
            "modified_by": <user_id>,
            "modified_date": "12341234",
            "favorite": true,
            "users": [
                <user id>,
                <user id>,
                <user id>
            ]
        }
    ],
    "archived_project_count": 10
}
```

I'm noticing the service call done by the backend is completing successfully (by looking at my Network tab in Chome Inspector), but it doesn't seem to run anything in the `then` block called in `viewmodels/projects/list.js` (tested this by adding a console.log("i'm here") line before `self.projects(jqxhr)`. I tried changing `then` to `done`, but still nothing. Instead, I see in the console the jqxhr object, followed by "Cancelling Navigation".

As a side note, I'm also wondering if there is a better convention within Durandal to make a variable set in main.js to be accessible throughout the app. So far I've had to use `window.service = [Object]` but it seems like there should be another method available. I was thinking of trying to setup the backend as I did with utils and config in main.js, but I need a config value to create the backend in the first place, so I figured that wasn't an option.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: At the risk of sounding very slightly negative - totally impenetrable! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what was going on here: the JSON I was receiving wasn't valid, so `then` wouldn't fire. It was helpful though to realize that, knowing invalid JSON won't trigger an error. Reason being: `<user id>` and properties like that were actually sent that way rather than being given as a number. Woops!

Comment: If you want error reporting all you need to do for most promise libraries (I haven't used this specific one) is call `.done()` or sometimes `.end()` on the end of the chain of promises.